# ListBox ItemsSource doesn't work from XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to bind listbox from xaml, but seems I am doing something wrong with it. Here is my XAML Page.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
<!--Pivot Control-->
<phone:Pivot Title="MY APPLICATION">
<!--Pivot item two-->
<phone:PivotItem Header="item2">
<Grid>
  <ListBox Foreground="Black" x:Name="ls" ItemsSource="{Binding MyLang}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Language}"></TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Grid>
</phone:PivotItem>
</phone:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
DataSource ds = null;
public List<TranslationLanguage> MyLang;
public PivotPage2()
{
    ds = new DataSource();
    MyLang = ds.getTranslationLanguages(); //return collections and contains 13 rows
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
}
public class TranslationLanguage
{
        [PrimaryKey]
        public byte LanguageID{get;set;}
        public string Language{get;set;}
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public FlowDirection FlowDirection { get; set; }
        public string DownloadURL { get; set; }
        public bool IsDownloaded { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

I am really confused why it doesn't work at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Binding can be done only on properties, `MyLang` is not a property. Make `MyLang` a property

```
public List<TranslationLanguage> MyLang{ get; set;};
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the datacontext bound from the code behind, you need to set the Datacontext of the Window as

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

Comment: <Window DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">... You need to set it as an attribute for the Window tag in your Xaml. After you add this you can remove the line "DataContext = this;" from the constructor

Comment: Also you need to change MyLang to a property as @ramb00 suggested, since binding works only on properties

Comment: well, the datacontext is set in the constructor: `DataContext = this;`. So no need to change it again

Answer (score -1):

You have to do like this:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}
```

Comment: well, the datacontext is set in the constructor: `DataContext = this;`. So no need to change it again